# SOQL Select in test setup?

Tags: apex, unit-test

In a test setup method I want to select an account and clone it for testing.
In the developer console I can select an account with this simple query:

```
SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1
```

When I use this query in a setup method, it returns nothing:

```
static void setupTestData() {
  List<Account> origList = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
  system.debug('size:' + origList.size()); // 0
  system.debug(origList); // empty list
}
```

Where is the difference between dev console and setup method? And how can I select an account in the setup method?

Comment: @testSetup method in test class is only visible  for test class.you can query it inside the test class and not from external program. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is in `TestMethod`  your org data is not available. This is a very good feature of Salesforce to prevent unwanted update of live data.

So first you need to create some test data and then you can use that.

```
static void setupTestData() {
  insert new account(Name = 'Test Account');
 }
```

You can also use `@SeeAllData` to access live data but if you update anything it will not be visible to others users.

Where Dev Console runs in current users mode and any changes which you made to data will be visible to all users

Comment: I would highly recommend **NOT** to use `@SeeAllData=true`. It does make writing test classes easier, but they are dependant on data, so if you would deploy to another sandbox/production which does not have the required data, your test classes will start to fail

Comment: @Novarg I never recommend this in my answer as well(thats why its half not complete written) :). I just want to explain all available solution to OP. Because in some use case `@SeeAllData=true` is only option available.

Comment: Suggest you remove the last 3 lines in the method - no purpose and the comments are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Tests are isolated from data that is in an org to ensure predictable results. Instead you must insert your own test data and an [@TestSetup](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses) method is a good place to do that.

See [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) for more details.